# Why is the R aggregation dropping data rows?

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyr

I have a data frame with 2 columns:  date & observations.  The data consists of multiple observations for each date.

```
 str(observations)
tibble [2,599 × 2] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ date        : chr [1:2599] "1/22/20" "1/22/20" "1/22/20" "1/22/20" ...
 $ observation : num [1:2599] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...

> tail(observations)
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  date    observation
  <chr>       <dbl>
1 5/13/20      4127
2 5/13/20      1042
3 5/13/20     14306
4 5/13/20      1066
5 5/13/20         0
6 5/13/20        89
```

I want to subtotal these observations to produce a single row for each date so I used this function:

```
subs <- aggregate(cbind(observation) ~ date,data=observations, FUN = sum, na.rm = TRUE)
```

But the output is missing any rows for the last 4 days of the original:

```
> tail(subs)
      date observation
108 5/4/20    128269
109 5/5/20    130593
110 5/6/20    131890
111 5/7/20    133991
112 5/8/20    135840
113 5/9/20    137397
```

Comment: Use `aggregate(cbind(observation) ~ date,data=observations, FUN = sum, na.rm = TRUE, na.action = NULL)`

Comment: Tried akrun's suggestion, but no joy.

Comment: Can you try `library(dplyr); observations %>% group_by(date) %>% summarisee(Sum = sum(observation, na.rm = TRUE))`

Comment: Can you create a small reproducible example where this behavior can be reproduced?

Answer (score 0):

I apologize.  On further investigation, it appears that the aggregate function returned that data out of order.  I re-ordered the data frame and confirmed that all dates were accounted for.